# Advice on implementing CMS capabilities in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system

I am building a small CMS for training content, on instruction of my client. I have recommended using an existing CMS, but he wants to look at me coding from scratch as well. Most other questions here on implementing a CMS focus on high level CMS features, e.g. templating, editing, SEO, routing etc. but I don't see much at all on the low level aspects, especially versioning of content etc.

To be specific: Are there any components or libraries I can look at for persistance and version management of what I call a `ContentItem` in my CMS, or good resources I can consult on doing this myself? A `ContentItem` is any large piece of text that should have change tracking, templated fields etc. E.g. standard emails, blog posts, training content, test answers, etc.

Pointers to something I could use for change tracking at Entity Framework level would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely simple to add versioning to any database table.  Just add an additional field for version, this can be a datetime, timestamp, or even just a sequence number that you add one to.  You make this a composite primary key with your exiting key (or even just a unique constraint) and you're golden.  The rule is, all updates are inserts.

It's really that simple.  Then in your queries you just always get the most recent version by default (doing a TOP 1 with an order by decending works well)

Comment: It can be that simple, but I will probably need a tiny bit more, such as which version is published etc. and 'branching' etc.

Comment: @ProfK - I don't know of many CMS's that support branching.  Most end-users would be confused by the concept (I know, i've tried to explain how it works when using version control for document management).  Of course, your "content item" would contain members related to publishing, but I was assuming you already understood that.  You were asking about versioning.

Comment: I was asking in general, about components or libraries that would include version management, assuming that such would have other facilities, not that I have already covered those.